# Linkbutton click event not firing via JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asplinkbutton

I have a link button on page which is rendered like this in html

```
<a id="lb_download" href="javascript:__dopostback...">download</a>
```

I am trying to trigger the click event of that button using JQUERY

```
$('#lb_download').click();
```

But its not firing. Direct clicking is working fine with the button. but using JQUERY is not

What I did wrong

**Adding little more details**
I tried a jquery event handler for the click event if firing or not

```
$('#lb_download').click(function(){
alert(10);
});
```

The weird part is its working and the alert is showing, but the post back or server side travel is not happening.. which happens when we click directly..

Comment: it should work. It depends when you trigger the click. If the click is triggered before the element is rendered then it won't work. See here > https://jsfiddle.net/qhupf6ce/

Comment: I dont know why.. its not firing even when we do $('#lb_download').click() from browser console itself.

Comment: try using `.trigger('click')` . Again, maybe the element is not rendered. Or , maybe you don;t have jQuery enabled. As you can see in the fiddle i shared, it works. Without more context, we cannot help you

Comment: Try to reproduce your issue in a snippet code, o link us your web project

Comment: @MihaiT , SilverSurfer I added little more details into the question..

Comment: Are you using web forms?

Comment: @DreamTeK Yes (aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Im able to solve the issue using eval as follows since the server side call is not occuring when using click() method of jquery.

```
eval($('#lb_download').attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked in my case

document.getElementById('lb_download').click();